# what to do to follow third level head in APA? like in the picture

Tags: apa-style

[image]Good morning. can somebody help. I got an issue with the heading in APA
here my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext]{apa7} %
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Design}
This section describes the study’s design.
\subsection{Procedure}
The procedure was fairly straightforward, yet required
attention to detail.
\subsubsection{Results}
Table \ref{tab:ComplexTable} contains some sample data. Our
statistical prowess in analyzing these data is unmatched.
\section{Discussion}
This is a lengthy and erudite discussion. It demonstrates amazing
skill in interpreting the results  for the masses.
\subsection{Erudite Discussion}
\subsubsection{Forthcoming}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the screenshot you provide above pertains to the APA7 guidelines? To me, they look exactly what APA6 used to specify. The formatting guidelines for sectioning headers (especially for those at the `\subsubsection` level) differ considerably between APA6 and APA7.

Comment: Off-topic: Since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, and since `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, the statement `\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}` may be simplified to `\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}`.

Comment: in APA7 guidelines they mentioned the same text, no change at all

Comment: Regarding: "in APA7 guidelines they mentioned the same text, no change at all": Please provide a source to that statement.

Comment: From https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/headings one can get the following information: level 3 heading: Flush Left, Bold Italic, Title Case Heading

         Text begins as a new paragraph. Which is definitely different than the image you show.

Comment: the title: :A pocket style manual" seven edition by Diana hacker and Nancy Sommers Page 85, my pdf file : the book does not have page number so i picked up the one show by Adobe reader.. in sixth edition page 49

Comment: @Chamanga: According to my research, the 7th edition of "A pocket style manual" was released in 2014, while the APA7 style guide was released 2019. So the book you cite can not refer to the APA7 style. I assume you are writing your thesis. Does your institution have any guidlines to which style they want you to use? If they specify "apa" style, it might be worth asking which version of the APA style they want you to use.